# How to integrate couriers service in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configuration, integration

I want to integrate a courier service like Fedex/Bluedart in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

**FedEx configuration**

If you have set up a FedEx sandbox and want to work in the testing environment, set Sandbox Mode to "Yes."

> Remember to set Sandbox Mode to "No" when you are ready to offer FedEx
>   as a shipping method to your customers.

[image]

**Package Description and Handle Fee**

> - Select the Packages Request Type to the option that best describes
>     your preference when splitting an order into multiple shipments:

- Divide to equal weight (one request)
- Use origin weight (few requests)

> - Select the type of Packaging typically used to ship products from your store. Options include:

- FedEx Envelope
- FedEx Pak
- FedEx Box
- FedEx Tube
- FedEx 10kg Box
- FedEx 25kg Box
- Your Packaging

> - Set Dropoff to the pick-up method that will be used for delivery. Options include:

**Regular Pickup**

- If you have a **high volume of shipments**, it can be cost effective
  to make arrangements with FedEx for regular pickups.

**Request Courier**

- You must call and request a FedEx courier to pick-up shipments.

**Drop Box**

- You must drop off shipments at your nearby FedEx drop box.

**Business Service Center**

- You must drop off shipments at your local FedEx business service
  center.

**Station**

- You must drop off shipments at your local FedEx station.

> - Set Weight Unit to the unit of measurement that is used in your locale. Options include:

- Pounds
- Kilograms

> Enter the Maximum Package Weight allowed for FedEx shipments. The default FedEx maximum weight is 150 lbs. Please consult your shipping
>   carrier for more information. We recommend using the default value,
>   unless you have made special arrangements with FedEx. See also:
>   Dimensional Weight.
>   [image]

**Config sales shipping methods fedex delivery methods**

[image]

**you can find multiple references for Magento Fedex**

1. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/fedex.html
2. https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-fedex-carrier-magento-2.html
3. https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/configure-fedex-carrier-magento-2/